# getting out of the directory when applying a tag

Tags: html, directory

How do I get out of the current directory *Dreamland* ?

[image]

I have to use the following tag in the *jsp* page inside the directory *Dreamland* :

```
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Currently it is unable to locate the *css* directory.

Comment: Add a `/` to the very beginning of the URL. That points it to the site root.

Comment: @Tieson T What does `./` mean ? _(with the dot)_

Comment: `./` means back 'up' one level.

Comment: @Tieson T Then what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: @TiesonT. For that one needs `../` (see my answer).

Comment: `/css/style.css` will point to the site root no matter how many directories down you put it. `../` and `./` are relative to wherever the referencing file is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`../` means up one directory level, one `../` puts you in the *Web Pages* folder

Comment: then what does `./` mean ? _(with one dot)_

Comment: as in if you're in *html* folder it selects the *html* folder

Comment: shouldn't there be just one `../` in your answer ? Currently I am in _Dreamland_ directory and I want to reach the _css_ directory

Comment: ah fair enough, I was looking at the highlighted page in the screenshot, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `/css/style.css`, or `../css/style.css` (if you are not using a server).

Comment: I am using a server _(Tomcat)_ . Please explain the dots. I have never  understood them

Comment: and what does server has to do with this ?

Comment: One dot means the current directory, and two dots means the parent directory. A slash in the beginning means the highest directory.

Comment: and why have you written _"if you are not using a server"_ ?

Comment: Because if you aren't in a server then `/css/style.css` would mean `C:\css\style.css` (on windows).